# How the world would change if it was possible to use Mind Uploading to upload the brain into customized artificial bodies?

Tags: culture, civilization, robots

I mean if in the future Mind Uploading become possible so people could create their own artificial bodies (robotic) and customize them in unique ways, even creating artificial bodies that would look like very different from their biological bodies.

For example:

- a black person could upload his/her mind into a blonde or a redhead body with very pale skin and light colored eyes and vice versa.
- A tall person could upload his/her mind into a short body and vice versa.
- A busty and curvy woman could upload her brain into a tall, straight and muscular woman body with different hair and facial shapes and features.
- Or a slender person could upload his/her mind into a fat or a muscular body.

People with some kind of dysphoria could benefit themselves from this and have higher self esteem.

I believe that even more unusual features could become possible. For example I think you could build a body with colorful skin, hair and eyes even with animal features like tails and wings (which would enable people to fly).

How would this change society? Would people's self esteem increase a lot? Or most will still prefer to accept the way they are and not to become an "android"? Will most people become beautiful? Do you think most people would choose a certain body type or will people become even more different from each other?

Comment: Society would change a lot. Or maybe it wouldn't. Who knows? Wasn't there a moderately successful [film which explored this premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogates)?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! It's certainly possible that there's a not-too-long answer to this, but at first reading, asking "How would this change society?" is quite a broad question, so is there something more specific that would be easier to answer in a smaller chunk? Of course, If there's multiple of these, you're free to make multiple posts.

Comment: I think you have a good underlying premise. But you are asking several questions at once and the basic question is very broad. Please edit your question to narrow the focus and reduce to a single question.

Comment: You need to watch a movie called *Surrogates*.

Comment: This question is incredibly broad. Perhaps consider changing 'society' to something much more targeted, like 'the mining industry' or 'cosmetics'. For now I'm VTC'ing.

Comment: Is it possible to use this technology to build a body in the image of someone else? if so there some disturbing identitiy theft implications.

Comment: The Netflix show *Altered Carbon* also explores this concept and its results on society. The conclusion it comes to is that the real game-changer is that it allows rich people to buy immortality (for themselves or for people who benefit them), thus removing death as the last social equalizer.

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty broad.  Here are a few changes to the world:

1. **Immortality**

By re uploading to new bodies every time they wear out you become immortal.  Most rich people will live forever, as long as they can afford a new body.  It might become a new retirement goal.  You work forty years to pay for a younger body.   How much does this cost, anyways? People might date someone who appears to be their age, but is actually a century older.  A married couple would likely get their body swaps at the same time.

2. **Duplication**

Can a person continue to exist while the new body with the uploaded mind also exists?  If yes, someone will certainly do it.  Can you make multiple artificial bodies?  If I make a thousand miniature androids with my own personality, are they all citizens who can vote?  A factory owner will make thousands to work for him if they aren't citizens, and are cheap enough.

3. **Population Growth**

Points 1 and 2 show that population will grow.  Currently the most industrialized countries have the lowest birth rates. Your process will start in the richest countries.  Immigration may be reversed as scarcity and overcrowding set in. Eventually this may fuel space exploration.

4. **Accumulating Skills**

What if an old man with 60 years martial arts experience is transferred into a 20 year old Olympiad body?  Same with every other skill.  Eventually some people will be super elite.  Pro athletes will become more skilled, or else it will be banned like steroids.  In 3000 AD, your history professor was actually alive in 2018.

5. **Body Modifications**

This is too broad to cover here, but many people would acquire bodies with physical abilities vastly improved over a normal human.  A few would choose assume weird forms of all kinds.

6. **Editing Mind State**

As a programmer, I think of this any time someone mentions Mind Uploading.  If a copy of the workings of a brain can be stored and replicated in a computer, someone WILL edit them.  A mind upload is really just a sophisticated artificial intelligence.  People will alter the mind to make a thinking factory, and make slave-robots, and make genius robots.  Its your story though, so you could just say the Mind-Upload is the original person still.

7. **Consciousness**

The near-future version of a mind upload is an AI copying the neurons of a human brain.  If that is what your version is, then the consciousness of the patient will end upon the upload.  Just because the new robot acts like you doesn't mean that it is you, or that you are experiencing it.  For this to work, you will have to say the soul of the person is transferred into the robot, or something similar.

Comment: Robotic bodies would be inorganic and would never age and deteriorate.Have you ever watched The Bicentennial man?

Comment: You're right, I hadn't properly read the question when I typed that part.

Comment: @user18428 Inorganic bodies would actually wear out and need replacing <i>faster</i> than organic, because organic bodies are able to repair themselves. If the inorganic bodies have constant external maintenance to replace the constant internal maintenance our current bodies supply, then it's immortal, because inorganic maintenance is easier to implement. Then again, planned obsolescence may strike, to keep the robot-builders in business long after everyone's a robot. Not to mention the inevitable updates.

Comment: The inorganic robot body could maintain and heal themselves with internal nanobots and/or self healing materials, so robots would not need external maintaince.